# RecyclerView Widget view not matching parent width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to get a widget to display and match the parent width in a RecyclerView, but it either doesn't show up, or it is not matching the width.

The layout seems to be working fine, because when I inflate it directly (without the widget), it has the layout display perfectly, but I need to use the `MyWidget` class because it has a lot of logic and sets up the view.

**This works, but isn't using the widget class:**

```
//(In RecyclerViewAdapter)
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View groupView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(groupView);
}
```

---

**Attempt 1:**
When I tried `this` and `false`, it doesn't display at all in the RecyclerView. It's completely empty:

```
//(In RecyclerViewAdapter)
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget(parent);
        return new ViewHolder(myWidget);
}


public class MyWidget extends LinearLayout {

    public MyWidget(ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent.getContext());
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, false);
    }

    //Important widget methods here.
}
```

---

**Attempt 2:**
If you keep it the same as above, but just change the inflate method to use the parameters `this` and `true`, the layout width is way too small. It doesn't fit the parent width:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true);
```

---

**Attempt 3:**
When I tried the same code, but with `parent` and `false`, it's completely empty again:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
```

---

**Attempt 4:**
When I tried the same code, but made it also attach to the LinearLayout superclass, then it displayed, but did not match width again:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);
addView(view);
```

---

**Attempt 5:**
When I tried the same code, but with `parent` and `true`,

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, true);
```

I got this error (scroll right):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                       
Process: PID: 19221
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null object reference                                                                                            

    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2913)                             
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)                                                                  

    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)                                                                                               

    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)                                                                                                 

    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)                                                                                                 

    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)                                                                                                 

    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
```

---

What else can I try? How can I get this to work properly like the first example, but using a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I just had to set layout parameters manually in `onCreateViewHolder`, and then use the parameters `this` and `true` in the inflate method. Special thanks to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28593053/2423194) where I found the code for setting the layout parameters manually in the onCreateViewHolder method.

```
//(In RecyclerViewAdapter) 
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
        MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget(parent);

        //Set layout parameters
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //width
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//height
        myWidget.setLayoutParams(lp);//override default layout params

        return new ViewHolder(myWidget); 
} 


public class MyWidget extends LinearLayout {

    public MyWidget(ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent.getContext());
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, this, true);
    } 

    //Important widget methods here. 
}
```