# RecyclerView row item layout not keeping dimensions defined in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am creating custom LinearLayouts for use as a row item in a RecyclerView. There are two fragments using two RecyclerViews with two adapters, using the one layout as defined by XML. Both fragments display the same unusual behaviour when it comes to sizing the row item but understandably so since they use the same layout file and practically the same slightly modified adapter/fragment code.

Here's the layout file pool_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/betPool_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/betPool_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/betPool_padding_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/courseRace_margin"
    android:id="@+id/stakepool_background">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stakepool_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stakepool_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/betPool_text_size"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The containing LinearLayout has its height set to 100dp, and its width set to match_parent, but the view displayed by the RecyclerView has varying widths that change every time the view is redrawn.

Here's the parent of the LinearLayout, the fragment's RecyclerView as defined by XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pools_frag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/brb_cyan"
    tools:context="com.ineda.terminal.fragments.pools.PoolsFragment">


<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/pools_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_200"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:visibility="gone" />


</FrameLayout>
```

This width is also set to match_parent, and it's parent (not included) is defined by a main_activity XML with relative layouts, so the view width *should* be sized as the width of the fragment as defined in main_activity minus the margins etc, but it just isn't.

```
public class PoolsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String POOL_SELECTED = "com.ineda.terminal.fragments.ppol.POOL_SELECTED";

    private Context context;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private PoolsAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Pool> poolList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Pool currentPool;
    private TextView overlay;

    private Pool previousSelection;


    public PoolsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getContext();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pools_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new PoolsAdapter(poolList, context);
        overlay = view.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)     view.findViewById(R.id.pools_recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Fragment code, in case you think it's relevant but I suspect it's not.

Adapter code:

```
public class PoolsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PoolsAdapter.holder> {
    private static OnPoolClickListener OnPoolClickListener;
    private List<Pool> pools;
    private Context context;
    private View previousSelectedPool;
    private Pool currentPool;
    private boolean initialised;

    public PoolsAdapter(List<Pool> list, Context context) {
        this.pools = list;
        this.context = context;
    }


@Override
public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new holder(new StakePoolButton(context));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final holder holder, final int position) {

    currentPool = pools.get(position);
    holder.button.getButtonText().setText(pools.get(position).code);

    if (!initialised) {
        if (position == 0) {
            OnPoolClickListener.onPoolClick(currentPool);
        }
        initialised = true;
    }

    if(currentPool.getStates() == null){
        currentPool.setStates(ButtonStates.UNSELECTED);
    }

    switch (currentPool.getStates()){
        case UNSELECTED:
            holder.button.colourAsDeselected();
            break;
        case SELECTED:
            holder.button.colourAsSelected();
            break;
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    holder.button.setLayoutParams(params);
    }


public class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    StakePoolButton button;

    public holder(StakePoolButton view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        button = view;
    }
```

I force the layout to resize itself at the adapter level, because it was a hacky way of making it at least look alright, but this will not work long term especially if the app is going to go onto multiple devices or need to be resized etc. This is done through LinearLayout.LayoutParams which forces the layout width to wrap_content after the layout has been inflated and all that. If I then go onto the XML and make the custom layout's height smaller, the text contained within does not shrink to match, meaning the thing is out of line.

Here finally is the Custom LinearLayout itself, although I'd be surprised if it was the problem :

```
public class StakePoolButton extends LinearLayout {     //button used for both the stake and pool fragments.

    private TextView buttonText;
    private LinearLayout stakePoolBackground;
    private Context context;

    boolean stake;  //false means pool

    private Typeface font;

    public StakePoolButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public StakePoolButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public StakePoolButton(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context){

        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.pool_layout, this);

        this.context = context;

        this.font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin_Regular.ttf");

        buttonText = findViewById(R.id.stakepool_name);
        buttonText.setTypeface(font);
        stakePoolBackground = findViewById(R.id.stakepool_background);

    }

        public void setData(Pool pool){
        buttonText.setText(pool.code);

        this.stake = false;
    }

    public void setData(Stake stake){
        buttonText.setText(String.valueOf("£" + stake.getStake()));

        this.stake = true;

    }
```

I have other custom LinearLayouts that work perfectly, and can be adjusted properly by changing the width and height values of the containing layout, but this one does not work for whatever reason.

edit: On the left we have the expected behaviour, which is forced by setting LayoutParams after inflation. On the right we have the behaviour when it isn't forced post-inflation. Widths are all variable, and change every time the view is reloaded.

[image: Expected and actual]

Comment: Post expected and actual screenshots.

Comment: @azizbekian done :)

Comment: As a test,  try placing two RecyclerView's into one Fragment. The layout parent for the RecyclerView's should be LinearLayout with the orientation set to horizontal. The  give the two RecyclerView's weight of "0.5dp" to force them each to occupy half the screen. See if you get the constant width sizes you were expecting. Also as a side note, when you have to views inside of a LinearLayout with the width and height to match_parent, you will not be able to see any additional sibling Views.

Comment: Have you try to change WRAP to MATCH layout params for holder.button in adapter ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana changing wrap to match makes the views' height = the height of the entire screen, so that only one view is displayed at a time. The width as set in layoutParams is already set to Match_Parent though, so it's not the problem. I want to reiterate that I do not want to be setting layoutParams at the adapter level. The dimensions are, and should be, defined in the XML

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem of this width variation is because you must add one more setting to your recyclerview.

So in your PoolsFragment

add this

```
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

after this line of code

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

**EDIT 2**

According to Drew's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591367/different-width-of-layout-inside-recyclerview-and-normal-linearlayout) it seems that it would be better to give the params manualy like this

so in your adapter class

```
//update this according to the answer I linked
@Override
public holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 View itemview=new StakePoolButton(parent.getContext());
  RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, //width
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);//height
        itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);//override default layout params


return new holder(itemview);
 }
```

and as you see height is wrap_content but you can change it to 100dp and the width should stay match_parent

Comment: Sadly this changed nothing. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: This throws up a lot of null object references on inflated layouts, TextViews etc

Comment: @Richardweber32 okay wait remove the false and wait till I update my answer

Comment: @Richardweber32 see second update , check the link that I added it is close to your problem.

Comment: @svi.data EDIT 2 did the job for me. However, I did not bother trying to use mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) when I saw EDIT 2, as I think it would provide a failproof solution in almost all the situations.